# Force publisher to publish an update?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

In the `init()` of my `ViewModel`, I have 2 subscribers.

1. The first one subscribes to downloaded data within `DataProvider()` and updates `downloadedData` with the result. This makes an API call and usually takes a few seconds before publishing data.
2. The second one subscribes to `$savedData` and then updates the `filteredData` array only with data that is contained in the `savedData` **AND** the `downloadedData`.

The problem is that the `downloadedData` takes time to download, while `savedData` is instant (it's actually in Core Data). After it downloads, I want to force an update to the second observer above (`$savedData`) to update the `filteredData` accordingly.

**Is there a way to manually force a publisher to publisher a value? On ObservedObjects, we can call `objectWillChange.send()` but is there something like that I can call on `$savedData`?**

*Disclaimer: This is a super-simplified version of my app. Please do not include answers that change the hierarchy. I also realize that I can add another publisher on $allCoins to mimic the one on $savedData, but I'd rather just force an update to $savedData. Thanks!*

```swift
    import SwiftUI
    
    struct TestView: View {
        
        @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
        
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                ForEach(vm.filteredData, id: \.self) { user in
                    Text(user)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            TestView()
        }
    }
    
    import Combine
    
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        
        @Published var downloadedData: [String] = []
        @Published var savedData: [String] = []
        @Published var filteredData: [String] = []
        var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
        @Published var provider = DataProvider()
    
        init() {
            // WHEN THIS GETS PUBLISHED...
            // CAN I FORCE A PUBLISH / UPDATE TO savedData?
            provider.$data
                .assign(to: \.downloadedData, on: self)
                // here?
                .store(in: &cancellables)
            
            $savedData
                .map { (saved) -> [String] in
                    return saved.map { (savedItem) -> String in
                        return self.downloadedData.contains(savedItem) ? savedItem : "NO"
                    }
                }
                .assign(to: \.filteredData, on: self)
                .store(in: &cancellables)
            
            getSavedData()
        }
        
        func getSavedData() {
            savedData = ["ONE", "TWO"]
        }
        
    }
    
    class DataProvider: ObservableObject {
        
        @Published var data: [String] = []
        
        init() {
            getData()
        }
        
        func getData() {
            // simulating api call
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                self.data.append(contentsOf: ["ONE", "TWO"])
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As other answers mentioned, `assign(to:on:)` can cause memory leaks. However, since iOS 14 you can use [`assign(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/just/assign(to:)) which is safe to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be thinking about the problem in a wrong way.

First, let's get the terminology right. You are *subscribing* to 2 publishers inside your `init`. Both of these publishers emit a value whenever their respective property changes.

What you seem to want to do is to update `filteredData` whenever `savedData` or `downloadedData` changes. So, instead of "forcing an update", you should subscribe to the kind of publisher that emits what you want when you want it. You can use `CombineLatest` to achieve this:

```
$savedData.combineLatest(provider.$data)
   .map { (saved, downloaded) in
      //...
   }
   .sink { [weak self] value in
      self?.filteredData = value
   }
   .store(in: &cancellables)
```

<sup>(Don't use `assign` - it creates a strong reference to `self`; use `sink` with `weak self` instead)</sup>

Comment: Yesssssss!!! This is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: In iOS 14 Apple introduced [`assign(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/just/assign(to:)) which is safe to use. So you could just do `.assign(to: & filteredData)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to downloadedData and assign it to saved data:

```
$downloadedData
    .assign(to: \.savedData, on: self)
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

Please refer to the following link as using `assign(to: on:)` causes memory leak when `self` is passed as a parameter.

https://forums.swift.org/t/does-assign-to-produce-memory-leaks/29546/11

Your other subscriptions also call `assign(to: on:)` with `self` as a paramter, and it would be a good idea to implement the solution in the link as it resolves this issue throughout the whole application.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this isn't what I was asking.